# Win 7 time service error

Tags: windows-7, time-synchronization

I see a warning in my Win7 Events Log:

The time service has not synchronized the system time for 86400 seconds because none of the time service providers provided a usable time stamp.

The message suggests that I run:

w32tm /resync

When I try to run that command, I get an error:

The following error occurred: The specified module could not be found. <0x8007007E>

I can run w32tm with no arguments and get the expected list of w32tm commands, so the program is accessable and runs.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Is this computer joined to a domain or is it standalone? Can you ping time.windows.com?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a firewall issue; verify that UDP port 123 is open to your time source.  The source will be the domain controller for domain-joined machines, or time.windows.com for standalone.  To get an idea of what NTP servers you are configured to use, and how well in sync you aren't, you can use:

```
w32tm /monitor
```

(Ping testing won't much help diagnosis because ping is ICMP, a different protocol than the UDP that carries NTP. So it's like using your bicycle to verify you can drive somewhere in your car - but your car has a flat tire.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  The Microsoft Knowledge Base Article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978714 and the associated hot fix solved it for me.